# React Native: Unable to click debugging menu

Tags: xcode, react-native

When pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> in the iOS simulator, the debugging menu transitions in slowly. Clicking on any of the options doesn't do anything. I then have to stop the project and start it again.

Xcode 6.4
React-Native 0.11.4
OSX El Capitan

[image]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Select your simulator and open "Debug" menu and uncheck "Slow Animations"  (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) to make the animation speed normal.

Comment: Awesome this was a great help!

Comment: that was damn annoying. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: This happened to me when I accidentally pressed ⌘ + T. Thank you.